# How to avoid console output about unsupported operations ? (IWebBrowser2, DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND)

Tags: c++, com, mfc, activex, ole

CONTEXT:
I'm trying to use IWebBrowser2 to create little embedded browser for viewing local html files. I'm doing this with help of MFC and CWnd::CreateControl in particular. Everything works well, except one moment: When I clicking on html links I recieve messages (to Visual C++ debug console) about COleException has been thrown. Browser opens links well, and there are no other observable effects, except messages in console
I was able trace place of throwing. There is callstack:

`AfxThrowOleException(...)
COleDispatchDriver::InvokeHelperV(...)
COleControlSite::InvokeHelperV(...)
COleControlSite::InvokeHelper(...)
COleControlSite::GetProperty(...)
COleControlSite::GetStyle(...) 
CWnd::GetStyle(...)
CWnd::OnDisplayChange(...)
CWnd::OnSettingChange(...)
CWnd::OnWndMsg(...)
CWnd::WindowProc(...)
AfxCallWndProc(...)
CWnd::SendMessageToDescendants(...)CWnd::SendMessageToDescendants(...)
CWnd::OnDisplayChange(...)
CWnd::OnSettingChange(...)
CDialog::OnSettingChange(...)
CWnd::OnWndMsg(...)
CWnd::WindowProc(...)
AfxCallWndProc(...)
AfxWndProc(...)`

After some investigation I know that MFC tries to call "Invoke" for IWebBrowser's IDispatch to receive "ENABLED" state of web browser control. Control in it's turn through return value tells that
such request can not be satisfied. MFC throws exception (and catches it by itself) and pollutes debug output.
QUESTION: What can I do to avoid or suppress this messages ?

ADDITIONAL INFO:
This is error message:

`Warning: constructing COleException, scode = DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND ($80020003).
RaiseException: Thread=9f84aba4 Proc=8c24c980 'HtmlHelpBrowser.exe'
AKY=00000401 PC=03fb542c(coredll.dll+0x0004542c) RA=8000a700(NK.EXE+0x00009700) BVA=00000001 FSR=00000001`

I'm doing all this stuff on Windows CE 5.0 with Visual C++ 9.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cause: COleControlSite::GetStyle() check DISPID_ENABLED and DISPID_BORDERSTYLE, two dispatch ids that IE did not implement. The GetStyle call is right on the call stack.

solution:

- Ignore the debug output, or
- Derive a class from COleControlSite to override GetStyle, copy COleControlSite::GetStyle's implementation except those lines that read the style from the ActiveX. Then [override CreateControlSite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w9b4e0zd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in the webbrowser's parent window's class and use the new control site. For VC6 or earlier, CWnd::CreateControlSite does not exist, and [overriding the control container is required](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/236312).

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for the answer, second solution has solved my problem very well. It has one little drawback: all hosts of my IWebBrowser2 based control (Dialog boxes etc.) should implement CreateControlSite method. Are there any variants to encapsulate CreateControlSite in my IWebBrowser2 based control ?

Comment: You can derive a class from CDialog and add CreateControlSite implementation there, then use the class as the base class of your dialogs.

Comment: Will consider this as one of ways. Thanks for help.